# Transcompile jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know all internal jQuery functions are written in JavaScript, so it should technically be possible to just evaluate jQuery to JavaScript.

I have a snippet of JavaScript that uses jQuery that I need to use in an environment where jQuery isn't available.
I know I could translate it by hand, but it is quite a lot of code.
Is there a tool out that that does this?

Just to make it clear: with a lot of effort I could probably get jQuery in the environment but I would like to have a solution that is a bit more resource friendly.
If there is no tool like this I'll just try to translate the code by hand, I was just wondering whether there was such a tool.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. There is no border to cross here. I would think it is impossible to extract "just the necessary parts" from it, you should focus on getting jQuery into your environment, if you need it.

Comment: I know jQuery is built up from JavaScript. I'm not saying I would like to extract some parts of jQuery. Say I have $(".classname"). This would be roughly equivalent to document.getElementsByClassName("classname"). I was just asking if there is a tool that does this kind of stuff programmatically.

Comment: No, there isn't. Everything in jQuery depends on everything in jQuery. While there might be easy substitutes for easy cases, even with your simple example there is a problem: not every browser supports `getElementsByClassName()`, but every browser jQuery runs on supports `$(".classname")`.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering if there was a tool that helped with replacing jQuery statements with the actual underlying code. I take it there is no such tool.

Comment: No, because the eventual outcome of such a tool would be the jQuery library (give or take).

Comment: According to the Closure Compiler posted beneath, I can shave off about 50% of the library, so I'll go with that.

Comment: If that works for you, use it. You'd just have to do it from scratch every time you change your code. I've not consistently had good experiences with the output of the closure compiler in advanced mode, but I also admit that I did not even think of that as an option. +1 for not giving up easily. :)

Comment: This is a reasonable question.  I was also looking for a transcompiler hoping to map jQuery to native inline JavaScript for various reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)'s advanced optimization compresses your code to only include parts that are necessary, so the parts of jQuery that *aren't* used are stripped away.

Comment: Is it necessary to copy and paste the whole JQuery code in that website?